How does the centripetal force change when the radius changes?
The centripetal force for a constant radius is $m\frac{v^2}{r}$, but what if that radius is changing as you're spinning the object. Say a spring with a spring constant $k$ that is being spun with a constant angular velocity $\omega$. How would the velocity look like? since $v=\omega r$ and the radius is changing. What is the overall expression for the centripetal force?

Beside the radial and tangential component of the equations of motion you can find in Michael Seifert answer, I'd like to stress that the force acting on the point mass depends on the physical systems and phenomena interacting with it and equals $m \ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ by the second principle of Newton dynamics.

This can be found by writing out Newton's Second Law in polar coordinates.  Specifically, the radial and tangential components of the net force acting on an object are given by
$$
F_r = m (\ddot{r} - r \dot{\theta}^2) \qquad F_\theta = m (2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta} + r \ddot{\theta} )
$$
Of note:

If the object is accelerating in or out ($\ddot{r} \neq 0$), then the radial component of the force is no longer just $r \dot{\theta}^2$ (the centripetal force you're familiar with).
If the force is purely radial ($F_\theta = 0$), then we must have $2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta} + r \ddot{\theta} = 0$.  This turns out to be equivalent to saying that $m r^2 \dot{\theta} =$ constant, i.e., the angular momentum of the object is a constant.  This implies that the tangential component of the velocity ($v_\text{tan} = r \dot{\theta}$) increases when $r$ decreases, and vice versa.

